# Best method for stopping the main game loop from a detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I'm working on a C++ game using SDL. I got started following [Lazyfoo's tutorials](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php) and have been building this in MacOS using XCode. This weekend, I've been seeing if I can get it compiling on Windows in Visual Studio 2019. I've been successful but I'm unsure about one of the changes I've had to make.

The game uses ImageMagick (Magick++) to do some drawing which is then stored as a texture in the video card memory using SDL (SDL's own drawing functions aren't quite enough). The drawing part of this is *very slow* but doesn't need to happen synchronously so I opted to put that process in its own thread which worked absolutely fine on my Mac.

Now I have this running on Windows, I was seeing occasional crashes when the game tried to draw a new character. I narrowed this down to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`, which is called from within the thread and creates the new texture using the surface created from the Magick++ Image. This only happened when I used multithreading, if I disabled that (and killed my framerate whenever it drew something), it worked fine.

I looked at mutex but all the recommendations advised using `join` on the thread which would have blocked `main()` for the full duration of the drawing and rendered this pointless. I think there's a very good chance I've misunderstood this!

Instead, I set up two `bool`s in a class that is passed as a reference to the thread. When `SDL_Thread_Waiting` is set to `true` by the thread, the game loop in `main()` pauses temporarily and sets `SDL_Main_Paused` to `true` which tells the thread it can safely access the renderer. The thread then sets `SDL_Main_Paused` to `false` when finished and the game loop continues.

It means that ImageMagick can be as slow as it needs to be in its own thread but, on the last step, I can briefly pause the main game to allow for the texture to be stored without any crashes.

Example code below. The game is pretty huge at this point but this should show what I'm doing:

```cpp
// class.hpp
Class Game {
    Public:
    bool is_running;
    bool SDL_Thread_Waiting = false;
    bool SDL_Main_Paused = false;
    // ...
}
```

```
// main.cpp
Game game;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {    
    game.is_running = true;

    while (game.is_running) {
        // Regular game stuff!

        if (game.SDL_Thread_Waiting) {
            game.SDL_Main_Paused = true;
            while (game.SDL_Main_Paused) {
                // do.. nothing?
            }
        }
    }
```

```
// Threaded bits
void generate_character() {
    std::thread th(make_texture, std::ref(game));
    th.detach();
}

SDL_Texture* make_texture(Game& game) {
    // Heavy lifting by ImageMagick goes here

    SDL_Thread_Waiting = true;
    while (!SDL_Main_Paused) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(25));
    }

    // SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()

    SDL_Main_Paused = false;
    SDL_Thread_Waiting = false;
    return texture;
}
```

Is this a suitable way to briefly block the main game loop from a detached thread? Am I misunderstanding `mutex` and would that be a better fit here?

I'm very new to C++ and SDL, I apologise if my entire question is based on further misunderstandings!

Comment: The `bool` variables written in one thread and read in another need to be `std::atomic<booL>`.  Also have a look at [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is a mutex behaviour. You have implemented poor spinlock - that may fail because of bad sync on lock variable (one thread may set variable but other not yet see this change), and wastes CPU cycles when locked as it keeps spinning in a loop. Use `SDL_mutex` or `std::mutex`, they seem to be what you wanted exactly.

As for accessing renderer from multiple threads - well, not so good. [SDL documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender) explicitly states that you really shouldn't (unless you're absolutely sure what SDL's renderer implementation is in use and know how this implementation behaves). Consider changing your approach - e.g. render to memory buffer/surface in separate thread, then signal it is ready so rendering thread can take the buffer and convert it into texture. You can even do double buffering here to minimise stall.

There are things that can be improved but require more work: creating thread isn't free, why not create it once and wait on mutex/semaphore/condvar for signal to render next frame? `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` assumes static texture, why not create streaming texture once and update it with `SDL_LockTexture` && `memcpy`?